# Second paint overrides first paint

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have two paints and set their colors to different colors. The problem is that the second paint overrides the first paint.

That's my code:

```
public class Score {
    static Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
    private Rect bounds = new Rect();
    private Paint paintBG = new Paint();
    private Paint paintFG = new Paint();
    private int mid;

    public Score(Paint paint) {
        this.paintBG = paint;
        this.paintFG = paint;

        // PROBLEME 
        paintBG.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paintFG.setColor(Color.WHITE); // <-- this paint overrides the paint before
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        String score = String.valueOf(g.getScore());
        paintFG.getTextBounds(score, 0, score.length(), bounds);
        mid = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (bounds.width() / 2);

        // different "paints" but the same color
        canvas.drawText(score, mid, 60, paintBG);
        canvas.drawText(score, mid, 50, paintFG);
    }
}
```

Best regards from germany. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amahfouz has explained the problem. One solution to the problem is to use `Paint`'s copy constructor.

```
public Score(Paint paint) {
    paintBG = new Paint(paint);
    paintFG = new Paint(paint);
    paintBG.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paintFG.setColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Both paints are referring to the same Paint object, the one passed as a parameter. So basically, both calls to setColor are modifying the same object and the last one is the one that sticks!

zum wohle!

Comment: So how I can fix that without two parameters? I thought that paintFG and paintBG inherit the values of the Paint object separate and I can modify them.

Comment: I see you already got an answer. Please mark this one as done. Thanks!